# YUI datatable column resize event

Tags: datatable, yui

I need to trap the manual resizing of a column width. Then store all the column widths into a cookie so that the next time the page is loaded the columns can be set according to the user preferences.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't figure out from the documentation what event was required:

```
myTable.subscribe("columnResizeEvent", 
  function(event){
    var column = event.column;
    var key = column.getKey();
    var width = event.width;
    createCookie("myTable.columns."+key+".width",width);
  }
);
```

Where createCookie is a routine to write cookies. This approach allows the cookies to be read while the columns are being defined, but before the table is rendered:

```
for(var i in myColumnDefs){
    var column = myColumnDefs[i];
    var width=readCookie("myTable.columns."+
      column.key+
      ".width");
    if (width){
      column.width = parseInt(width);
    }
  }
```